# How to copy with the last 1 with pattern matching method in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a list like

```
{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6}
```

The `{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 9, 6}` is expected. Furthermore, if we want to change the last `1` into `100` to get `{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 100, 9, 6}`, how to do this?

Comment: Just for fun, without pattern matching: `ReplacePart[#, Last@Position[#, 1] -> 100] &@lst` or (a bit silly) `ReplacePart[#, Replace[Position[#, 1], {l_ :> Last[l]}] -> 100] &@lst`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way:

```
{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6} /. {x : Longest[___], 1, y___} :> {x, 100, y}
(*  {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 100, 9, 6}  *)
```

Another way:

```
{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6} /. {x___, 1, y : Except[1] ...} :> {x, 100, y}
(*  {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 100, 9, 6}  *)
```

Answer (score 8):

With

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6}
```

do

```
list[[Max @ Position[list, 1]]] = 100
```

then

```
list
```

> {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 100, 9, 6}

Comment: The `Last` position will be the `Max` number as well, so this symbol could be removed to write instead: `list[[Max@Position[list, 1]]] = 100`.

Answer (score 6):

```
l = 1; ({1,2, 3,1, 5,8, 1,9, 6}[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]] /. 1 /; l++ == 1 -> 100)[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]
```

You may argue `[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]` belongs to list manipulation, then the following is a more "pattern matching" one:

```
l = 0; {1,2,3,1,5,8,1,9,6} /. 1 :> (l++; o@100) /. o@100 /; (--l != 0) -> 1 /. o -> (## &)
```

Comment: It looks so... :)

Comment: (+1) Instead of [[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]] you could simply apply Reverse.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I was just pretending to write code without letter :D

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` and its 3rd argument

To replace from the end we have to `Reverse` twice (a negative `n` isn't allowed).

```
Reverse @ SequenceReplace[Reverse @ list, {1} :> 100, 1]
```

{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 100, 9, 6}

To replace the first two `1`:

```
SequenceReplace[list, {1} :> 100, 2]
```

{100, 2, 3, 100, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6}
```

**Using `FirstPosition`:**

```
g = ReplacePart[#1, -First@
       FirstPosition[Reverse@#1, #2, Length@#1 + 1] -> 100] &;

g @@ {list, 1}
```

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

```
h = ReplacePart[#, Last@PositionIndex[#1][#2] -> 100] &;

h @@ {list, 1}
```

---

*Result*

{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 100, 9, 6}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Reap`, `Sow` and `Scan`, we can build `ReplaceLastInstance`:

```
ReplaceLastInstance[list_List, target_, replacement_] := 
Module[{replaced = False}, 
Reverse@Reap[
Scan[If[! replaced && # === target, Sow[replacement]; 
replaced = True, Sow[#]] &, Reverse@list]][[2, 1]]]

list = {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6};
ReplaceLastInstance[list, 1, 100]

(*{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 100, 9, 6}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`Position`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) + [**`ReplaceAt`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAt.html)

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 9, 6}
Position[list, 1][[-1]]
ReplaceAt[list, 1 -> 100, Position[list, 1][[-1]]]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 8, 100, 9, 6}`